# How to set billing or shipping address using PayPal PHP REST API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using "paypal" payment method:

```php
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
```

I have tried the following, but it is not setting the address:

```php
$addr = new Address();
$addr->setLine1('34/1');
$addr->setLine2('xxx');
$addr->setCity('xxxxxxx');
$addr->setCountry_code('US');
$addr->setPostal_code('43210');
$addr->setState('OH');
```

Comment: You do not (cannot) set billing address when using PayPal as a payment method. You can suggest shipping address.

Answer (score 9):

1. Create [ShippingAddress](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/ShippingAddress.php) object.
2. `ShippingAddress` extends [Address](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Address.php) object. Therefore, set all of the `Address` object properties and `ShippingAddress` specific properties (`RecipientName`).
3. Assign the created `ShippingAddress` to the [ItemList](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/ItemList.php) using `setShippingAddress` method:

```php
$shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();

$shipping_address->setCity('City');
$shipping_address->setCountryCode('AR');
$shipping_address->setPostalCode('200');
$shipping_address->setLine1('Adress Line1');
$shipping_address->setState('State');
$shipping_address->setRecipientName('Recipient Name');

$itemList->setShippingAddress($shipping_address);
```

Comment: Ive tried adding the shipping address to the ItemList object and also the PayerInfo object but Im still seeing "Delivery Address: 
No address provided" in paypal